# Blender crashes repeatedly when leaving edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Blender seems to be crashing a lot for me, but I've discovered it only ever crashes when leaving edit mode, and, when it does, there's no warning, no error message, no "This program has stopped working" - it just dead closes out, as if I hit the close button.

**Is this normal? Is it crashing? Or is this some dumb shortcut or something I'm not catching?**

If it is crashing, and if I had to guess, it seems like it's crashing while trying to stow undo states, because it tends to crash when I do a lot in edit mode, and then leave (which made it *really* frustrating before I knew when it was crashing - now I just always save before leaving edit mode - no more problems).

<del>(p.s., someone plz create a 'crash'/'bug'/'issue'/something tag - I would with enough rep.)</del>

EDIT:

I'm using Blender 2.78 x64 on Windows 10 x64, 4GB RAM 
Blender's details line has the following:
Vertices: 31,346 | Faces: 20,460 | Triangles: 41,064 | Memory Used: 46.20MB

I didn't know if this was something I was missing, or something common. If this is just a legitimate bug, I understand this probably isn't the place to post.

Comment: We don't need "*'crash'/'bug'/'issue'/something tag*", this is not a bug tracker we can't do anything about them. If a software crashes it is never a normal thing. Is your object very complex? What are your system specs? Under what operating system? What Blender version? Are you by any chance working close to your system memory or performance limits?

Comment: With that amount of memory left, it's bound to crash. Clear up some space for a bit. I have 300GB left of memory and I can still work freely with a million vertices.